# Как переопределить файл стилей wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть файлы со стилями, которые подключаются через `wp_enqueue_style`, мне нужно чтобы bootstrap файл со стилями не перекрывал файл main-style. Как сделать такое?чтобы они отдельно работали, размер шрифтов был от main-style, а не от bootstrap

```
function tea_scripts() {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'tea-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
          wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/css/style.css', array("tea-style"));
            wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array("tea-style") );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-carousel', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/css/owl.carousel.css', array("tea-style")  );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-carousel-default', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/css/owl.theme.default.css', array("tea-style") );
          wp_enqueue_style( 'magnific-popup', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/css/magnific-popup.css', array("tea-style") );
          wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/css/font-awesome.min.css', array("tea-style") );

            wp_enqueue_script( 'tea-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20151215', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'tea-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );

            wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'magnific-popup-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'tea-main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

            if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
                wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
            }

        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tea_scripts');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы делаете ровно обратное, когда запускаете стили bootstrap после main, и не указывая зависимость от main. Надо так

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'tea-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array("tea-style") );
wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/css/style.css', array("tea-style", 'bootstrap'));
```

Для наглядности, я переставил строчки местами, но это уже не имеет значения. При любом порядке строк main подключится после bootstrap, потому что в нем указано третьим аргументом `array("tea-style", 'bootstrap')`.

Надо понимать, что wp_enqueue_style() не запускает стиль или скрипт, а ставит их в очередь, и порядок регулируется третьим аргументом. Он так и называется - зависимость (dependency).

Непосредственно запуск скриптов из сформированной очереди WordPress осуществляет позже, в другом событии.